# Creating a new obj-c class and "targeting" current project

Tags: xcode5

I am the newest of new to learning objective C, as I have started experimenting with it today. I am following the "become an xcoder" pdf, which is rather outdated. 
Right now I am trying to create my first application with a GUI and the pdf tells me to create a new "Objectice-C class" and instantiate it into my current project.
It seems the way this works has been entirely revamped in Xcode 5 though, because I have been googling for a way to do this and am only finding ways that let me select the target group when creating and saving the new objective-c class.
I simply cannot figure out how to "link" the new class to my existing application.

Could someone be so kind to explain this for me?

EDIT: As a reply to the comment below, maybe I have not been clear enough.
The situation as it is now, I have already made a new Cocao Application and have filled the window with 2 buttons and a text box, giving them names. The next step this guide tells me to take is create a new obj-c class and "instantiating" it in the application already made. That's where things go wrong.
I'm not sure if the guide is really still a viable option to follow seeing as it is so outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Mac application with a GUI is most easily done using the "Cocoa Application" template. You can find that among the many other templates when you create a new project. It comes with an empty xib file (your basic GUI) hooked up to AppDelegate.

[image]

You don't need to create a new class. What you want to do needs nothing more than the AppDelegate. What you might want to look into the concepts IBAction and IBOutlet.

You set up an IBAction to tell you code when a button is clicked, and you set up an IBOutlet to the text field so that you can change its contents.

Comment: What is the purpose of your app? What should the new class do? Things are changing tremendously with each new SDK release. Why do you use an outdated tutorial?

Comment: I am trying to make an app that has nothing more than two buttons and one text field. One of the buttons is supposed to fill the box and the other button is supposed to reset it.

Comment: Have decided the tutorial I was following is simply too updated to succesfully follow.